# Mysql database not updating when PHP script executes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have a timeout function that runs correctly except for one thing.  The field that checks if a user is currently logged in does not update once the script runs.  I was testing it all week and got it to actually work, but when I tried to test it today, I stopped updating the field.  Can anyone explain why?  I also have a logout button that does a jQuery call which runs a logout.php script when the button is clicked which works perfectly.  Could this be why the timeout script has stopped updating the database?  I don't think that could what it is, but I could be wrong.

**timeout script(php)**

```
<?php
    require("../includes/header.php");
    $now = time();
    $expires = $_SESSION["expire"] + 30;
    $user = $_SESSION["id"];

    if(!isset($_SESSION["expire"]) || $expires > $now){
        $_SESSION["expire"] = $now;
    }
    else{
        mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE `$user_table` SET `logged_in`=0 WHERE `user_id`='$user_id'");
        session_unset();
        session_destroy();
        mysqli_close($connect);
        header("Location: timed_out.php");
    }
?>
```

**logout script(js & php)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#logout").on("click", function(){
        $.post("../php/logout.php", {}, function(response){
            if(response.success == "1"){
                location.replace("../pages/logged_out.php");
            }
        }, "json");
    })
})
```

**logout script(php)**

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    require("../includes/header.php");
    $user_id = $_SESSION["id"];

    ob_clean();
    mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE `$user_table` SET `logged_in`=0 WHERE `user_id`='$user_id'");
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    mysqli_close($connect);
    echo json_encode(array("success"=>1));
?>
```

Another question I have is.  Would it be beneficial to do the timeout script in jQuery instead of PHP?  If so, how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need some simple debuggin ;)

Your login script says in the query:

```
WHERE `user_id`='$user_id'
```

but the code a bit higher says

```
$user = $_SESSION["id"];
```

That's NOT the same variable ;)

Comment: GAAHHH!  Thank you!  I was loosing my mind trying to figure out why.  I must've done an accidental delete at some point.

Comment: same as his logout function

Comment: @Dorvalla nope, that says `$user_id = $_SESSION["id"];`

Comment: Indeed they do.  Thanks again

Comment: @Robert That's where error reporting and checking for DB error comes in very handy ;)

Comment: @Fred-ii- I have error reporting turned on, however, it actually wasn't kicking back an error, which was confusing the hell out of me.  But there also wasn't anything causing a logical error.

Comment: @Dorvalla my logout script was setting `$user_id = $_SESSION["id"]` whereas the timeout script was setting `$user = $_SESSION["id"]` while the SQL was trying to match the `user_id` field to `$user_id` in both scripts

Comment: @Nanne my bad, didnt see he defined it

Comment: @Robert what about displaying them? Here's what I use `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: That's probably where I'm going wrong.  Each time you tell me to add that to my script and I don't do it until after you mention to do so.  Perhaps I should write myself a note to add that so you don't have to keep telling me to do it.

Comment: @Robert ah, so you weren't "displaying" them?

Comment: No.  I was displaying the SQL errors, but not any others.....It's been a week, that's my excuse.